# Return occurence of letters in order in the string

Tags: php

I made this code to return the number of occurrences of letters in a string.
this function returns '6a3b5y' but I want it to respect the order and display '4a3b2a5y'
how to change it to display  '4a3b2a5y' ?

```
function encode($input) {
    $l = mb_strlen($input, 'UTF-8');
    $unique = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) {
        $char = mb_substr($input, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');
        if(!array_key_exists($char, $unique))
            $unique[$char] = 0;
        $unique[$char]++;
    }
    $a=[];
    foreach($unique as $k=>$val){
    $a[]= $val.$k ;
    }
      return implode("",$a) ;
}
echo encode('aaaabbbaayyyyy') ;
```

Comment: Google "run length encoding", since that's what you're trying to implement.

Comment: You can't use an associative array for this, since that doesn't handle duplicates in different parts of the string.

Comment: You should just be checking if the current character is the same as the previous character. If it is, increment the counter. If it isn't, output the counter and the character, then reset both variables.

Comment: i thought about it but i don't know how to do it with php synthax

Comment: `if (mb_substr($input, $i, 1, 'UTF-8') == mb_substr($input, $i-1, 1, 'UTF-8'))` will tell you if the current character is the same as the previous character.

Comment: thanks I already did that with if () in a for loop and a counter but I couldn't display the result correctly

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? This looks like a good exercise to learn TDD :)

Comment: yes i'm learning php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable to hold the previous character. Compare the current character to it. If they're the same, increment a counter. If they're not, output the previous character and counter, then reset the variables.

At the end, output the final character and counter.

```
function encode($input) {
    $output = '';
    $l = mb_strlen($input, 'UTF-8');
    $prevchar = mb_substr($input, 0, 1, 'UTF-8');
    $count = 1;
    for($i = 1; $i < $l; $i++) {
        $char = mb_substr($input, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');
        if ($char == $prevchar) {
            $count++;
        } else {
            $output .= "$count$prevchar";
            $count = 1;
            $prevchar = $char;
        }
    }
    $output .= "$count$prevchar";
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, i just understood and it works